# How to add my street address to Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I see other people have had an issue getting their address on Google Maps. Mine too is a new development.  No can find it because it is not listed on any maps.

Comment: Apart from Google Maps, there are other maps available. Especially, have a look at OpenStreetMap: https://www.openstreetmap.org - there, you can edit the map and add features yourself. From my experience, in many contexts it has more detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

The following link has an answer to your question
https://support.google.com/maps/thread/7805975/how-can-i-add-my-residential-address-to-google-maps?hl=en

> To add an address to the Map, please enter your address into the
> search bar of the Map. If your address doesn't show fully, remove any
> house numbers or apartment numbers and the marker should locate you in
> the middle of the road.   Click on "Send feedback" in the bottom right
> hand corner of the screen, or click on the menu (3 horizontal lines
> top left of screen) and scroll down to "Send feedback".   Click on
> "Wrong Address" and complete the form (if you have an apartment
> number, please add it to line 2 of the form, and if your address has 3
> lines, you will be given an option to add a third line).    IMPORTANT:
> Do not abbreviate anything but spell everything out (Street, Road,
> Boulevard, North, Southeast etc). Google's algorithms will
> automatically abbreviate map data depending on where it is displayed,
> but it's essential that the full address be entered without any
> abbreviations.   Only make an entry on "Street address line 2" if you
> are entering an apartment or suite number.  In all cases uses the
> format of #3 (for an example of apartment number 3). Do not enter any
> text such as "Apt" or "Suite" or "Floor" -- as such an address (with
> text in Line 2) will not parse correctly in Google Search.   Should
> you be in a country using 3 lines for an address, after entering
> information in "Street address line 2" an option box will appear ("Add
> Line")  that you may click on for a third address line.   Next move
> the Map to the exact location of your address. You can change to
> Satellite view and change the zoom if needed. You need to make sure
> that the pin is directly over your house.    Click on "Done" when
> you're happy that the marker is in the correct location.   Finally,
> click "Send" to submit this to Google Maps.   You will receive an
> email after submitting the edit request. It will say "Thank you for
> adding an address to Google Maps! The address is being reviewed. We'll
> let you know once the changes are published."  Please KEEP this email
> as you might need it later if the edit is not approved after one
> month, or if it is incorrectly denied.   To check the status of your
> edit go to Your Contributions, then click on Edits.  You can then
> scroll down and see the current status of your edits.  If your report
> is still "Pending" after one month, or "Not Applied" please post again
> with a screenshot of the email, mentioned above, and we will chase up
> Google for you.